# Why are eps files of the graphics of my latex document covnerted to pdf?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, conversion, eps

The graphics in my latex document as eps image files and I would like the latex output pdf file to be as small as possible in size and with higher resolution, but whenever I run the compiler of the tex file I found the eps files are converted to pdf (...-eps-converted-to.pdf) and the output pdf file is bigger than what I wish!

How should I suppress the conversion of eps images to pdfs? 
In other words, I would like to keep eps without the conversion step when run the compiler of tex file

Comment: you need to convert to pdf to include in to pdf, a pdf file can not contain an eps file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But you must admit that it *would* make the PDF smaller if the files weren't converted :-).

Comment: Thanks David Carlisle and cfr for your response. So this means the intermediate step of eps conversion to pdf is necessary and the new generated graphic files with extensions (-eps-converted-to.pdf) should be exist when I run the compiler, I thought these files new pdf could be as a hidden step or something! Then, I shouldn't worry about their existence I mean (...-eps-converted-to.pdf) files?

Comment: pdftex can not include eps, the converted pdf files are left so that you only need to do the conversion once, when you run pdflatex the next time it will re-use the converted pdf files, which is much quicker.

Comment: So, I shouldn't worry about those new pdf files of the graphics, (i.e., -eps-converted-to.pdf) files?

Comment: no why are they worrying?

Comment: No:) I thought the conversion of eps to pdf could be as internal step or something!

Comment: tex was designed in 1982 and holding graphics files in memory wasn't really an option on a machine with 540K of memory:-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80581/discussion-between-mhdella-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to include the data into a pdf document you need to convert the EPS to pdf, the converted files are not deleted but left in the current directory so that the conversion only needs to happen once. On later runs of latex it will re-use the converted files made on the first run.